# Google Sheet scripts

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-query

I created the following script to sort data on certain pages in google sheets, and it will only run the second function and not the first one. I am new to programming and switching over to sheets from excel. I am sure its something small and obvious, but i can't figure it out. I appreciate any help.

```
function onEdit(event){
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
if(sheet.getName() ==='ADMIN')
var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

var columnToSortBy = 1;
var tableRange = "A2:G48"; // What to sort.

if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
}
}

function onEdit(event){
var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
if(sheet.getName() ==='HQ', 'ARMT', 'MAINT', 'AVNX', 'SHOPS')
var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

var columnToSortBy = 2;
var tableRange = "A4:D40"; // What to sort.

if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
 } 
}
```

Comment: I don't see it, but someone else might if you give them a chance to see the sheet by sharing a link to it (maybe just view only) so they can copy it and play with it.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript and google scripts, functions are objects. What you are doing here is creating an object (function onEdit) and then creating it again.  It's like setting a variable named xyz to 4 and then setting the same variable to 14.  The last one set is all that matters.  You can accomplish what you want by merging the functions together so you have one onEdit, or naming one(or both) differently and having the onEdit call them.

```
 function onEdit(event) {
     first(event);
     second(event);
 }

 function first(event) {
     var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
     if (sheet.getName() === 'ADMIN')
         var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

     var columnToSortBy = 1;
     var tableRange = "A2:G48"; // What to sort.

     if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy) {
         var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
         range.sort({
             column: columnToSortBy,
             ascending: true
         });
     }
 }

 function second(event) {
     var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
     if (sheet.getName() === 'HQ', 'ARMT', 'MAINT', 'AVNX', 'SHOPS')
         var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

     var columnToSortBy = 2;
     var tableRange = "A4:D40"; // What to sort.

     if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy) {
         var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
         range.sort({
             column: columnToSortBy,
             ascending: true
         });
     }
 }
```